# How to integrate SVG file?

Tags: javascript, svg

There is a scenario, the buildings picture as a background, each top of the building has a  display block, and the data in the block can be change by JS. 
  Can I try the way like below:
    Firstly, convert the building picture(PNG format) to SVG file;
    Secondly, add the display blocks on the buildings as SVG elements 
I just start to learn about SVG, so have no idea if it's possible to implement in this way.

[image: sketch map]

Comment: What have you tried/ What are you asking? Why SVG? Why convert to PNG? What code are you using or trying to use? I think you need to do a little more research so your question is clearer and your needs better defined. We are not here to help you with researching the stuff you want us to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is the [`<image>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) element in SVG specifiation to render complete file into specific rectangle.
2. You could use CSS or JavaScript plugins to show or hide any elements in dependence of another element hovering. For example

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 256 256"
     preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet">
     <defs>
     <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      .sensor {
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .sensor:not(:hover) + .hidden:not(:hover) {
        display: none;
      }
      .hidden {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
     </style>
     </defs>
     <image x="0" y="0" height="256" width="256" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5DHd.png"/>
     <rect class="sensor" x="0" y="10" height="200" width="100"/>
     <g class="hidden"><text x="20" y="75">WOMAN</text></g>
     <rect class="sensor" x="110" y="30" height="220" width="140"/>
     <g class="hidden"><text x="130" y="100">MAN</text></g>
 </svg>
```

Run the snippet and move mouse pointer over image.

Comment: thanks for you giving me a simple but very useful example. Then I can work on this way to my target. Thanks!

Comment: @Lisa, I am glad. You could use rectangles, lines, patches and other elements to create complex shapes for "sensors".